# AngularJS data-binding with DOM not working while using D3js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am implementing the force-layout graph using D3js.
I have implemented a directive where I have implemented the graph.

Now I wanted to fetch some data from the back-end upon clicking on each node.
I am trying to implement it in an AngularJS controller.

The ajax call is fine - it is returning the data as expected. The problem is that the data changes are not reflecting on the DOM.

The HTML

```
<div nodes=some-nodes links=some-links force-diagram></div>
```

The AngularJS directive

```
app
.directive('forceDiagram', [function () {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'VisualizeCtrl',
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        var links = $.parseJSON(iAttrs.links);
        var nodes = $.parseJSON(iAttrs.nodes);
        ...
        ...
        var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 10)
                    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
                    .on('click', function(d) {
                        // call to a function in the controller
                        return scope.pullData(d);
                    });
        ...
        ...
    };
  }
}])
```

The AngularJS controller

```
controller('VisualizeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http' function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.payload = {id:0, text: ''};
  $scope.pullData = function (data) {
        url = 'index.php?r=' + data.node;
        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
        success(function(payload) {
            console.log(payload); // this is fine
            $scope.payload = payload;
            console.log($scope.payload) // this is also fine
        }).
        error(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
    }
  }
}])
```

But in the following HTML, it is not showing up

```
<div ng-controller="VisualizeCtrl">
  <div class="diagram" nodes=some-nodes links=some-links force-diagram></div>
  {{payload}} <!-- this is not showing any changes -->
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try running $scope.apply() at the end of your success callback

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Got errors like this. `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest at Error (native)`

Comment: Please create a working example on a site like JSFiddle that we can look at. Personally, I don't understand how this is set up. I doubt your nodes are even getting passed in to the directive because Angular won't evaluate nodes=some-nodes as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $scope.$apply() to make sure the DOM is updated.
See more here: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

The following code should work.

```
success(function(payload) {
        console.log(payload); // this is fine
        $scope.$apply(function() {payload = payload;});
        console.log($scope.payload) // this is also fine
}).
```